# How to set liquibase classpath

Tags: jhipster, liquibase

I created a JHipster project. I would like to run the liquibase changesets manually. By default the changesets are included from the classpath. The changelog is in `src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml`, and the changesets are in `src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">

    <include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
    <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-changelog - JHipster will add liquibase changelogs here -->
    <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-constraints-changelog - JHipster will add liquibase constraints changelogs here -->
</databaseChangeLog>
```

When running `mvn liquibase:update`, I get an error because the changesets are not in the classpath even though the file exists:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.3:update (default-cli) on project playground: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.SetupException: classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml does not exist -> [Help 1]
```

So I try to run from the command line by setting the classpath.

```
liquibase --classpath=src/main/resources --classpath=postgresql-42.1.3.jar 
--url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/playground 
--driver=org.postgresql.Driver 
--changeLogFile=src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml 
--username playground --password=***** update
```

with the same error: `Unexpected error running Liquibase: classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml does not exist`

A workaround is to remove the reference `classpath:` in the include part but I would like to avoid to edit the file each time a changeset is added by jhipster when using `jhipster entity` or `jhipster import-jdl`.

Comment: Can you set the classpath twice?  I see two `--classpath` flags.  Also note that this was changed yesterday and classpath will be removed in future versions of JHipster https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/6121

Comment: I put two `--classpath` because I couldn't find the syntax for a single `--classpath`. I tried with `;` separator but did not work. It seems removing `classpath:` will be the future solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to run `mvn process-resources` before running a liquibase command, so the files under `src/main/resources` will be in the `target/classes` folder. And then remove the `classpath:` part as stated in https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/6121

Answer (score 2):

well... I faced the same problem due I don't want that jhipster automatically update the production database.

So starting with @Sydney suggestion I decided to write a new profile in **POM** that changes the `'classpath:'` word in process-resources phase, and for that I used an `ANT` plugin for make an replacement over `master.xml` file to `<empty>`.  So this was a result:

```xml
    <profile>
        <id>only-liquibase</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <changeLogFile>target/classes/config/liquibase/master.xml</changeLogFile>
                        <driver></driver>
                        <url></url>
                        <defaultSchemaName></defaultSchemaName>
                        <username>dentalaser</username>
                        <password></password>
                        <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:ec.com.dentalaser.domain?dialect=&amp;hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&amp;hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy</referenceUrl>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <logging>debug</logging>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                            <version>${javassist.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                            <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                            <version>${liquibase-hibernate5.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                            <version>${validation-api.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <target>
                                    <echo>Reemplazando el classpath el archivo a desplegar en AWS</echo>
                                    <replace file="${project.build.directory}/classes/config/liquibase/master.xml" token="classpath:" value=""/>
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

After that from command line execute something like this:

`./mvnw process-resources liquibase:updateSQL -DskipTests -Dliquibase.url="jdbc:postgresql://<IP>:<PORT>/<DATABASE>" -Dliquibase.password="<supersecret>" -Ponly-liquibase`

or this:

`./mvnw process-resources liquibase:updateSQL -DskipTests -Dliquibase.url="offline:postgresql" -Ponly-liquibase`

I really hope that this help you!!!

Comment: Please observe the `changeLogFile` in maven config, due this is set due `target` folder and not `src` folder.