# Classpath not finding file

Tags: javascript, node.js, jar, classpath, liquibase

I want to add a jar file to my classpath but I am getting the error `Unexpected error running Liquibase: 'C:\jar\migrations-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar' does not exist`.Do I have to write the absolute path? Is there any way to use the path relatively to `ìndex.js`?

```
const POSTGRESSQL_DEFAULT_CONFIG = require('liquibase').POSTGRESSQL_DEFAULT_CONFIG;

const myConfig = {
  ...POSTGRESSQL_DEFAULT_CONFIG,
  changeLogFile: 'db/master/changelog.xml',
  url: 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/saft-demo-dump?allowMultiQueries=TRUE',
  username: 'postgres',
  password: '*****',
  classpath:"/jar/migrations-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
}
const instTs = new LiquibaseTS(myConfig);
```

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: If nothing else, don't use an absolute path, which is what you're doing now. For example, your `changeLogFile` is not an absolute path.

Comment: @DaveNewton so in node.js a / means absolute path?

Comment: In *anything* it means an absolute path: `/` is the root directory. This may not be sufficient to solve the program, but it's clear that it's incorrect--see how the error is showing the JAR path at the root level?

Comment: @DaveNewton removed the / and now I get this error `Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: org.postgresql.Driver`.Do you have any idea why? If I delete classpath the build is successfull

Comment: Likely because it expects the classpath to be complete, but I don't know anything about liquibase. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45129985/438992 might (or might not) help.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have a hint that maybe it has something to do with my jar, since I didn't add it to my pom file. I say this because it  is a java.lang exception

Comment: No, it has something to do with your classpath: once you specify a classpath the classpath must be complete, hence it can no longer find *other* classes, like the JDBC driver. That's why the linked post provides an option other than setting the classpath.

Comment: "Cannot find database driver" tells you that you are not providing the jdbc driver for postgre. I guess your Custom Java Migration needs it? Putting it next to your Custom Migration should do the trick

Comment: @glace I already did that and it worked. Now only the final piece of the puzzle is missing. How do I access my class in the XML file?